# Cisco AnyConnect VPN Disconnects Internet with TP Link router

Tags: cisco, anyconnect, tp-link

I use a [TP Link Archer C20 Wirelss Dual Band Router](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/cat-9_Archer-C20.html) to connect to fiber broadband service.

For my office work, I connect to a VPN network, which works fine for sometime. And after a while, the VPN breaks the internet connection. None of the router clients are able to connect. The router is back up only when I reboot it.

After a little digging, I noticed that even my DOS protection is turned off, with all the attack filtering options disabled.

What might be causing the sudden drop in internet connection? I'm on a Ubuntu machine with Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility VPN Client.

Comment: You haven’t mentioned why you think a VPN client running on a single machine is the cause of your router failing for your entire network? Sounds like a bad router.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with an Archer C50 and Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility VPN Client on macOS. I need to reboot the router after a while. Did you find a way to solve the problem?

Comment: No. Not yet. Still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be blocked due to UDP flood filtering consider under Security DDoS settings.

You may disabled the settings and verify. It will help to resolved the issue.